# R loop with get function with different parameter

Tags: r, loops, assign

i create data frame from the following url,

since i've several sites i need to run this script for each site (for example in the attaches example site 1 and 41) and then rbind all the of them to one

```
LS_Bellaboo_Token <- xxx
url_signature_orders_report <- "https://ran-reporting.rakutenmarketing.com/en/reports/signature-orders-report/filters?include_summary=Y&tz=GMT&date_type=transaction"
from <- Sys.Date()-39
to <- Sys.Date()-1

site <- 1 
LinkShare_Report_1 <-
  read.csv(text=rawToChar(
    GET(url_signature_orders_report,
        query=list(token=LS_Bellaboo_Token,
                   start_date=from,
                   end_date=to,
                   network=site))
    [["content"]]),skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep =',')
if (length(LinkShare_Report_US$X..of.Items)>0 )
{LinkShare_Report_US["site"] <-"US"}

site <- 41 
LinkShare_Report_41 <-
  read.csv(text=rawToChar(
    GET(url_signature_orders_report,
        query=list(token=LS_Bellaboo_Token,
                   start_date=from,
                   end_date=to,
                   network=site))
    [["content"]]),skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep =',')
if (length(LinkShare_Report_US$X..of.Items)>0 )
{LinkShare_Report_US["site"] <-"US"}
```

instead of duplicated them for each site i want to create loop.

i'm trying the following script

```
site <-c(1,41)
for (i in site){
LinkShare_Report_[i] <-
  read.csv(text=rawToChar(
    GET(url_signature_orders_report,
        query=list(token=LS_Bellaboo_Token,
                   start_date=from,
                   end_date=to,
                   network=site))
    [["content"]]),skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep =',')
}
```

but it doesn't work for me , i'm new in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to first create your object `LinkShare_Report_`.

```
LinkShare_Report_ <- list()
```

Then you can run

```
site <- c(1,41)
for (i in site){
 LinkShare_Report_[i] <-
  read.csv(text=rawToChar(
     GET(url_signature_orders_report,
         query=list(token=LS_Bellaboo_Token,
               start_date=from,
               end_date=to,
               network=i))
[["content"]]),skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep =',')
}
```

Since the list creates empty elements for anything between 1 and 41, it would be more parsimonious to use assign, creating a new object for each site.

```
site <- c(1,41)
for (i in site){
 assign(paste0('site',i),
  read.csv(text=rawToChar(
     GET(url_signature_orders_report,
         query=list(token=LS_Bellaboo_Token,
               start_date=from,
               end_date=to,
               network=i))
[["content"]]),skip = 4, header = TRUE, sep =',')
)
}
```